# Confusion on the multinomial distribution

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, multinomial-distribution

So we can think of the multinomial distribution like the binomial distribution except that there are more than two outcomes.

In the binomial distribution, each trial is independent of each other(i.e. Bernoulli Trials), so we use the binomial distribution in probabilistic situations where we draw **with replacement**. Likewise, we should also be using the multinomial distribution for situations where we **draw with replacement**, correct?

However, the following solution doesn't hold if the above is True. For reference, this comes from "The Probability Tutoring Book" by Carol Ash.

> 60% of students are against a policy, 30% of students are for the policy and 10% of students are indifferent. Find the probability that of ten students selected at random, 4 are for the policy, 5 are against the policy, and 1 is indifferent.

The answer

> $\frac{10!}{4! 5! 1!}(.6)^5(.3)^4(1)^1$

I understand where the fraction comes from - we can arrange the 10 students in $10!$ ways, choosing the same 4 students just in a different ordering is double counting them so we divide by $4!$ and likewise for the students against the policy.

However, isn't the multinomial distribution only applicable if we draw **with replacement**, in this case, we can't choose a person twice when we select the 10 students, so why are we allowed to do so here?

Comment: Yes, this is a poor example: if the number of students is large it will be approximately true, but if say there were only $20$ students and we picked a subset of $10$ of them, the answer here would be appreciably off.

Comment: Indeed.  The presumption is that each student will independently answer with the given *rates* when asked,  rather than that we *actually* know the exact counts of students on a particular campus.

Comment: The issue has nothing to do with multinomial.  If there were only two choices, the trouble would remain.

Comment: @herbsteinberg Oh that's true because we're still drawing without replacement.

Comment: @AnginaSeng So just to be clear we're allowed to treat it like a multinomial distribution because we're assuming there's a huge population size?

Comment: Look at exactly what happens if there are only ten students as compared to one thousand, particularly after the first pick.  When you don't replace, the probabilities change.